# How do I check for repeating data within a time period?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with a time column and another column with value.

I want to select any rows with identical values within a time frame, for example within 1 hour. I am not choosing a time frame to select, I want to select all data in my table of the rows with repeating data in a time frame of a length I specify.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear, at least to me.

Comment: Need more information: SQL engine for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely to be slow, but something like:

```
 SELECT
     A.ValueColumn,
     A.DateColumn,
     B.DateColumn
 FROM MyTableName AS A
 JOIN MyTableName AS B -- You want two copies of the table so you can find ones with the same value in the timerange
     ON B.ValueColumn = A.ValueColumn -- Obviously you want the value to be the same
 WHERE
     -- You want entries where B is at least as old as A, and at most one hour later
     B.DateColumn BETWEEN A.DateColumn AND DateAdd(Hour, 1, A.DateColumn)
     AND
     B.PrimaryKeyColumn != A.PrimaryKeyColumn -- Just make sure the entries aren't the same element joined onto itself
```

A is our first table and B is the second, this allows us to join the table to itself to compare the entries. We start by matching these tables on the value, then we filter entries to ensure that the entry we're comparing to for B was created sometime between A created and A created + 1 hour. The final check is to try and avoid situations where the A and B tables would match an entry to itself.